# Remove LI from UL on click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

So I have a INPUT TEXT that upon keypress=enter prepends an LI to an UL

The LI contains a LINK that gives the user the option to remove it from the UL

HTML (on page load)

```
<ul id="conditionList"></ul>
```

after ther user inputs some conditions, the UL gets populated with LI

```
<li>condition<a href="#" class="clearitem">x</a></li>
```

However, in my jQuery

```
$('#conditionList a.clearitem').click(function(){
$(this).parent().remove();
});
```

will not work!

Is it because it's not recognizing the new LI's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deprecated since 1.9. use `on` instead of `live`.

Use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of `click` there because your link is generated dynamically:

```
$('#conditionList a.clearitem').live('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**.live()**

> Attach a handler to the event for all
>   elements which match the current
>   selector, now or in the future.

Depracate since 1.9. use `on` instead of `live`.

Comment: Depracate since 1.9. use `on` instead of `live`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an event binding that's going to recognize created elements.  This should do that:

```
$('#conditionList a.clearitem').live('click', function () {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the LIs are added to the DOM after the click event handler has been declared? If so, you might want to look into using live() instead of bind():

```
$('#conditionList a.clearitem').live('click', function(){
$(this).parent().remove();
});
```